Participles vs Infinitives question on the old-model TOEFL test
I found a question like this while prepping for the TOEFL:

(A. Sprints) are equipped with starting blocks (B. to help) sprinters
to push away quickly and some equipment time (C. to record) (D.
runners’ time).

This is the type of question where you have to find the mistake in a given sentence.
The answer key says the answer is C. I understand that the key is leading me to understand that the sentence should use 'recording' instead, but I'll be honest - I think the sentence sounds fine as is. Where is the mistake there? And if it should say 'some equipment time recording', as in the process that the equipment is doing, then why doesn't the first clause also use 'starting blocks helping' in the same manner (the process of helping the sprinters?)

If you're supposed to read the sentence including the words in brackets, the word time before C doesn't make sense.

I thought so too, but since it isn't one of the options I tried my best to ignore it. Do you think any of the options is wrong? Or do you think the question is flawed to begin with?

The question is flawed. The only 'mistake' seems to be the first occurrence of 'time', though I think I would have used 'runners' times', since each runner completes the course in a different time.

But it's weird to say that "sprints are equipped".   It's the lanes of the track that are equipped.

"equipment time" is not "timing equipment".  "equipment time" makes no sense to me. "time equipment" would work.

@austere. As per Wikipedia, starting blocks have sensors to time the athlete's reaction to the starting gun. So what is meant by. "equipment time recording runners time."
Modern blocks used for world records now must have sensors that detect the pressure from the athlete and can be used to time their reaction to the starting gun. Athletes who react faster than one-tenth of a second can be charged with a false start and the race recalled.

@JamesMathai, is that why the equipment is described by the process of recording? So does that mean that the second part of the sentence is describing the process you mentioned and the first part is describing the purpose of the starting block?

@austere.  The consensus seems to be that your question is unanswerable since there is a mistake in test. I don't think you will find a useful answer to your question about this test, since the test is so badly written. You can delete your question if you accept that there is no possibility of a useful answer.

Yes, what an awful sentence. No way to recover it with only one fix.

@LukeSawczak unless the word time was repeated twice erroneously by the tester or the OP e.g. …push away quickly and some equipment  (C) for recording (D. runners’ time).

Sprints are equipped with starting blocks to help sprinters (to) push away quickly and some equipment to record runners’ time. Parallelism created.

I. Time recording meaning:
OP's query on why the infinitive is wrong in C*

(A. Sprints) are equipped with starting blocks (B. to help) sprinters to push away quickly and some equipment time (C. to record) (D. runners’ time).

The correct answer is
Sprints are equipped with starting blocks  to help sprinters to push away quickly and some equipment (which is)  recording runners’ time.
It describes what the equipment is doing—actively recording the runners' time.
II. Why "Time Recording" is Needed:
The issue in Part C lies with the phrase "equipment time to record.” This structure is awkward and unclear, suggesting an incorrect relationship between "time" and "equipment."
Corrected Sentence Options:

“some equipment recording runners’ time” — The present participle “recording” describes the ongoing action of the equipment, making it more logical.
“some time-recording equipment” — A compound adjective that clarifies the purpose of the equipment, indicating it is specifically designed to measure runners’ time.


III. What is Time Recording?.
.
Time recording typically refers to tracking and logging the start and end of tasks, especially in workplaces or manufacturing. For example, companies often use systems to monitor employees' working hours, shifts, and productivity.

In athletics, time-recording equipment serves a similar purpose: tracking performance and reaction times in events like sprint races. Although “time recording” is more common in industrial contexts, it functionally means precisely measuring time.
IV. If "Time" is Absent:
Without “time,” both infinitive and participial forms are grammatically correct:

"some equipment to record runners’ time” (expressing purpose).
“some equipment recording runners’ time” (indicating ongoing function).

V. Why "Helping" doesn't work in Part B:

"To help" is an infinitive of purpose, showing why the starting blocks are used:
“Starting blocks are equipped to help sprinters push away quickly.”
The infinitive explains the goal or intention behind the action.
"Helping" would act as a present participle, describing an ongoing action, not a purpose. This would suggest the blocks are actively helping at all times, which is not logical:
“Starting blocks helping sprinters push away…” sounds incomplete or awkward.

